# Blender show the model in orthography mode as transparent, although all settings are turned off

Tags: 3d-view, interface, wireframe

I'm going crazy over this problem. I don't understand how it appeared.
The problem occurs in orthography mode.
The model looks like it's in X-ray mode, but it's not. I can see the outer surface and everything behind it, they overlap each other and the view becomes unreadable.

[image: ortho projection with transparent grid]

I turned off all settings, but the problem remained. I also tried resetting the blender to factory settings, but that didn't help.

[image: options window]

If you turn off overlays, the problem will disappear along with all the auxiliary elements. This is not a solution to the problem.

[image: turn off all settings]

When you turn on perspective projection, the problem disappears - all internal surfaces disappear

[image: The problem disappears in perspective mode]

Please help me make the model opaque, like in the photo below. I feel like there is some setting enabled, but I can't find it.

[image: Good viewport]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured it out and hope this answer helps someone.
The problem is related to the clip distance. At very short distances, part of the model disappears.

[image: Too low distance]

If you make the range too large, the internal surfaces begin to appear.

[image: Too far distance]

The key to solving the problem lies in optimizing the clip distance. (1000m solved the problem for me)

[image: 1000 meters clip distance]

I'm sorry that I'm clogging up the forum with my stupid question. I hope this saves someone a little time.

Love everyone. Always yours, whitefox ^_^

Comment: Thanks for your self-answer. Glad you found it!  You can accept your own answer (with the tick) after a while, and that will mark it as solved for other readers.